# How to create a image transition hover effect with css without breaking the grid layout

Tags: html, css, grid, hover, transition

i want to create a transition hover effect on an image (cross-fade with another image) in CSS.The image is sitting in a grid layout.
The image crossfade works, but the grid breaks. The other fields of the grid slide behind the image. How can I fix this. Here's the code:

HTML

```
            <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="four columns"> 
                <div id="crossfade">
                <img src="images/vodafone-2.jpg" alt="placeholder" class="bottom">
                <img src="images/vodafone-1.jpg" alt="placeholder" class="top">
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="four columns"> 
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="placeholder">
                </div>

                <div class="four columns"> 
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="placeholder">
                </div>

            </div>
```

CSS

```
#crossfade {
position:relative;
}

#crossfade img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;    
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#crossfade img.top:hover {
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: Or maybe there is a more simple way to achieve this? I just want the image to turn darker and have some white text written over it.

Comment: Is this all the code required to replicate the issue I can't see the problem you are describing. Would you be able to put this into a working codepen or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the content inside the first ".columns" div are all absolutely positioned the div itself has no height. So what i've done is placed a transparent image as a placeholder into that div. I've added a ".fade" class to the images I want to apply the crossfade to, so that the placeholder image isn't affected.

Note: Judging from your HTML I am under the impression you are using Foundation as your framework?

```
<img src="http://www.officialiphoneunlock.co.uk/images/vodalogonew.png" alt="placeholder" class="bottom fade">
<img src="http://www.engagetv.com/sites/engagetv.com/files/logos/Vodafone-logo.jpg" alt="placeholder" class="top fade">
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" width="350" height="350">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/partypete25/vnxy83us/

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Unfortunately now I have an unwanted gap between this row of images and the next, which hasn't been there before. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I have removed the pixel height and width and there is no more gap and its working perfectly. Thanks a lot.